# More insights of ErrorMessage in Microsoft Online

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, office365-apps

I'm developing an Office.js based TaskPane Add-in. Recently I see frequently following error message which appears randomly:

> Sorry, there was a problem saving your document.
>
> Tell us about this problem to help us fix it. Give feedback to
>   Microsoft
>
> Session ID: 1334d772-005e-4fcf-9ef0-6d5e19b56865 Please tell Microsoft
>   about this problem. We have created an error report that you can send
>   to help us improve Word Online. This report will include a copy of
>   your document which we will only use to investigate the error.

How can I get insight into this "Report" which is being sent to Microsoft?

[image]

The console.log itself doesn't show anything. Is there a way to figure out what might have caused this message?

Even playing around with the Script Lab I receive the same popup error message.

The issue can be more or less reliably reproduced by

Openin

- opening a new word document in Microsoft Online
- Opening Script Lab Code
- Opening Script Lab Run
- Selecting the Code example for 'Content control basics'
- Running the example
- interact with the example to insert and modify content controls

After a random period of time, the message pops up

**Update:** Issue was addressed and fixed by the Microsoft Office Team:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/54#issuecomment-364346330

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code here within your question: [mcve]

Comment: Please specify the steps that lead up to the error message.

Comment: Hey @RickKirkham thanks for you feedback. Unfortunately there is no immediate way to replicate the error message above. I am using a minimal office.js addin which randomly shows this message in Microsoft Online only. The console does not provide any further message. 
Any help to debug deeper or figure out what the actual message is, would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Rob, thanks for your suggestion, I added the text of the dialog to my question.

Comment: @RickKirkham Instead of using my own addin as a use case, I started to play around with the Script Lab Office Add-in and can confirm same, unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes, I use the 'Send Error Report' feature every time I see it.

Comment: I also just found an issue report on Github, 
For reference:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/54